How I can pass the URI as a query param for my Blazor WebAssembly app?
I am creating a Blazor application with .NET 5.0, I need a parameter to be passed when starting the app that is used throughout the app, not just on one page of the app.
That is, while the app is being programmed it runs on localhost:port/
Right after the port, I want to define the parameter and have it read in the mainlayout and sent to the body (my mainlayout is attached).
In the body of the code, there are only 2 pages, and both pages consume components, I have found on the web how to pass it as a cascading parameter or a simple or even indexed parameter, but none of it has worked for me.
So what I require is something like this: localhost:port/param
I don't know if it is possible to do it this way, since this app must be a link that is opened from another desktop app by clicking and the browser opens with that parameter included
Or I don't know how I can tell my app that the initial page is not / but rather /page/param.
But I suppose that I only receive that on that page, and I also have a dropdown where I navigate through both pages and that is a component but at least that one I have seen how to pass a parameter to it
MainLayout:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page d-flex" >

    <section class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light pr-lg-2 flex-lg-row w-100 position-fixed" style="z-index: 2; background-color: @vc_rojoFrisby;">
        <div class="container-fluid p-1 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <nav style="color: white; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 20px;">Restaurante Rastreo Domi @vc_RestId</nav>
            <div class="text-center">
                <img src="/img/icono_frisby.png" alt="logo_frisby" class="img-fluid" style="max-height: 40px; height:auto; width: auto;">
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <nav style="color: white; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; margin-right: 10px;"> Restaurante: F54</nav>
                <DropdownMenu/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <CascadingValue Value="@vc_RestId">
    <div class="mt-2 ml-5 mt-lg-4 mt-xl-5 mt-md-5 mt-sm-5 position-relative" style="flex-grow: 1; width:100%;">
        @Body
    </div>
    </CascadingValue>>
</div>

@code
{
    public static string vc_rojoFrisby = "#E00109";

    [Parameter]
    public string vc_RestId { get; set; } = "";
}

I try searching in the web and i asked for it to chat gpt and gemini

I don‘t know about your project structure, but to pass in a parameter via the URL you have to use something like
@page “/{param}“

on root level or your MainLayout. See MSDC on passing in query params. You can then define this parameter as a Cascading Parameter and your components should be able to access it.
If you want to change the base path of your application, then you have to consider that the steps to do so are different based on which Blazor you are using (WASM, Server etc.). Refer to this MSDC, and follow the steps for your use case.
